# Changing backend language of Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

I have just signed up a Mailchimp account for my client but he doesn't speak English. Is there a way to switch the backend language of Mailchimp to German?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly there isn't a German interface as far as I can tell..